# Refresh value in datatable vuejs with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a data-table with values coming from the backend (laravel) I use the mixin to pass values to the backend, when I insert the value of sortBy and sortDesc in a standard date and update the page it is coming from a static form correctly, but when I click on the item and should update and bring the orderer according to the clicked this.sortBy or this.sortDesc he is not updating the values.

How can I force to update the values in the mixin and bring new data from the backend?

Data-Table

```
 <v-data-table
                  :headers="headers"
                  :items="items"
                  :options.sync="options"
                  :server-items-length="totalItems"
                  :sort-by="sortBy"
                  :sort-desc="sortDesc"
                  @update:sort-by="updateSort('by', $event)"
                  @update:sort-desc="updateSort('desc', $event)"
                  :loading="loading"
                  :footer-props="{
                    itemsPerPageOptions: [2, 10, 20, 50]
                  }"
                  class="elevation-1"
                >
```

Script

```
 export default {
        mixins: [ FromQueryPaginationTableMixin ],
        components: {
          HotsitesSelect,
        },
        data () {
          return {
            sortBy: ['expire_at'],
            sortDesc: ['desc'],
    }
    }
    }


methods: {
      updateSort(byDesc, event){
            if(byDesc == 'by'){
                this.sortBy = event
            }else if(byDesc == 'desc'){
                this.sortDesc = event
            }
        },
}
```

Mixin

```
const params = {
        page,
        order: this.sortDesc[0],
        orderBy: this.sortBy[0],
        perPage: query.perPage || this.defaultItemsPerPage,
        ...this.filterValues
      };

      if (query.s) {
        params.search = query.s;
      }

      if (this.orderBy) {
        params.orderBy = this.orderBy;
      }

      if (this.order) {
        params.order = this.order;
      }
      this.loading = true;
```

Comment: Should your mixin reference `this.sortBy` where it is referencing `this.orderBy`? (Second to last if statement)

Comment: the if is correct because it takes the value of the const params order. @CameronWilby

Comment: Are you sure?  I don't see how `this.orderBy` would evaluate given the component does not have that field in the data block

Comment: `params.orderBy` is correct, change `this.orderBy` to `this.sortBy[0]` and `this.order` to `this.sortDesc[0]`

Comment: I have changed as you said but have not updated the data on click yet, when I enter the value of? order = desc in the navigation url it works.